# Conda install screwed up my environment. Can I undo it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried installing rpy2 so that I could work with R files (`.rda`) using `conda install -c r rpy2`, and it totally screwed up my environment.

For example:

1) When I try importing **pandas**, I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'`

2) When I try importing **matplotlib**, I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'`

I wasn't having these issues before I installed this package. Is there a way to undo what I just did  - as if I never installed it in the first place?

Answer (score 85):

You can "roll back" to a previous revision. First, run:

```
conda list --revisions
```

You will get a list of revisions with their revision number. Then, look at the second-to-last revision and take note of its number. To revert to this revision, run:

```
conda install --revision N
```

where `N` is the revision number.

Comment: Hi, I just tried this and I got the error: `CondaRevisionError: Cannot revert to 15, since conda-forge::openssl-1.0.2p-h470a237_2 is not in repodata.` I've searched Google and am unable to get a grib on what this means and how to overcome it.

Comment: @Austin Are you in the base environment?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Comp Sci and, to be honest, I don't know if I'm in the base environment or not. How do I check? And, if I'm not, should I run this command from the base environment once I get there?

Comment: @Austin Your shell should look like this `(base) C:\Users\(username)>` with the environment name listed on the left. If you don't see it, you can always run `conda env list` and the environment with the start next to it is the active one. The main thing is, in general, you shouldn't be using the base environment at all.

Comment: Oh, ok. It turns out that I am in the base --> this is what I see:  `base                  * /Users/austin/anaconda3`. Any idea what I can do from here?

Comment: @Austin Yeah, you shouldn't be messing around with the base environment, as that's where your conda installation is. For the most part, you should be working in a separate environment. Anyway, this may require a reinstallation of `conda` after complete, but first you can try `conda update conda`, then roll back.

Comment: Yea, this will require reinstallation. Appreciate your assistance on this, Tomothy.

Comment: fyi if you're getting `conda-forge` related errors then specifying the channel may help e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge --revision N`

Comment: yes I am an idiot, I thought I switched to a different env but I didn't, is that unfixable? That happened for the second time and the first time I reinstalled conda as that isn't a big deal. Now though I have one environment with pytorch and that stuff takes ages to install

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use  [iz_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54172505/10141885) and had  `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 9 column 2` error after

```
conda list --revisions
conda install --revision N
```

Which was fixed with `conda clean -i` as described [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12709#issuecomment-1788009381)

Also, `conda clean --all` in the end seems was useful.

<sub>*Not sure if it was better to post this as well visible answer or lost in the comments or as edit suggestion - feel free to fix or comment on this.*</sub>