# I have messed a Virtual Environment up: how to go back

Tags: python, pip, conda

I had set a virtual environment up in Anaconda, using

`conda create --name myworkingenv`

I added then an Ipyhton kernel

```
   python -m ipykernel install --user --name myworkingenv --display-name "Python     (myworkingenv)"
```

and proceeded with installing certain packages. The main catch was that for certain compatibility reasons I needed
 `numpy==1.21.3`, which I managed to get.

It all worked fine and dandy until the day I got lazy and instead of cloning this environmen, I simply added a package to it, [missingpy](https://pypi.org/project/missingpy/), and worked on new adventures.

Some time later I went back to the old Jupiter notebook for which I needed this environment in the first place, and it does not work anymore, some other incompatibility kicked in.

I am at a loss for what to do.

In the old Jupiter notebook I did run

`!pip list --local`

(I guess this command returns also the packages installed with `conda install`, at least I hope...)

so I have a snapshot of the old virtual environment, it is a long list from `aiohttp 3.8.1` to `zope.interface 5.4.0`. Now how can I revert the actual virtual env to how it was before the installation of `missingpy` messed it up? It has been working great until then, I can only guess the latter installation updated some packages/modules (not `numpy` though, which is still the needed 1.21.3), and that kicked the incompatibility in.

What could I do now?
The brute force approach would be to manually check the version of each module mentioned in the list issued after `!pip list --local`, and see if and which package does not match the old, original virtual environment.
Is there any more efficient way?

Out of rush I started checking packages manually, starting from the most likely, and in this instance I found the culprit. But in a more general case, how should one proceed?
Would it be good practice to get the virtual environment snapshot with `!pip list --local` to a list, to be able to find any difference by simply comparing the old and the new one? It frankly looks nightmarish...

Comment: It seems like you can just uninstall `missingpy` - isn't that the obvious solution? I think there is also a kind of "history" that you can use to go back to earlier versions of you environment's package state... I'm a little fuzzy on that. What actual error are you getting? Why do you say it "doesn't work anymore"

Comment: @topsail, I uninstalled missingpy but it still did not work. I think installing missingpy updated other packages as well, and uninstalling it does not downgrade those. The error message is very specific to the problem, it has to do with how a certain scimitar-learn function produces output, which for some reasons works only for certain numpy versions, but there are god knows what other dependencies. My question is more abstract, in the general case, how can one reproduce an older environment, before some upgrades took place? That "history" thing you mention is what I am really looking for

Comment: quite a few pages on this, examples: https://blog.rtwilson.com/conda-revisions-letting-you-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-your-environment/ https://www.shriramjaju.page/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/ https://medium.com/@fengliplatform/how-to-downgrade-or-upgrade-python-versions-in-anaconda-distribution-44aecf606ec4

Comment: @topsail that is great, I would accept it an answer, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. It's okay as this is really a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172339/conda-install-screwed-up-my-environment-can-i-undo-it I will just downvote it as such since there is already lots of good explanations on this from this post and other sites with detailed descriptions of this feature.